# nslookup: error while loading shared libraries: libjson-c.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: networking, internet

20.10 uptodate.

What do I need here?

```
 nslookup <IP>
 nslookup: error while loading shared libraries: libjson-c.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please show output of `which nslookup` and `ldd $(which nslookup)` .

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall corresponding [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=groovy&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fnslookup) for 20.10:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bind9-dnsutils
```